# Зациклить анимацию посредством css3

Tags: css3

Есть у меня вот такой указатель: ssmaker.ru/622c6439. jpg

Интересно, можно ли его зациклить посредством css3? То есть, сделать прыгающим в низ в верх без помощи js.

```
<i class="down"></i>

.down {
    display: block;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    border-right: 3px solid #fff;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #fff;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Например так:

```css
.down {
    display: block;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    border-right: 3px solid red;
    border-bottom: 3px solid red;
    transform: rotate(45deg);

    animation: downUp 1s infinite ease-in-out alternate; /* включаем анимацию и задаем параметры */
}

/* анимация */
@keyframes downUp { 
  from {margin-top: 10px;}  
  to {margin-top: 70px;}
}
```

```html
  <i class="down"></i>
```

Смотрим в [доки](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-animation) и используем префиксы там, где необходимо

Анимация без `alternate`

```css
.down {
    display: block;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    border-right: 3px solid red;
    border-bottom: 3px solid red;
    transform: rotate(45deg);

    animation: downUp 2s infinite ease-in-out; /* включаем анимацию и задаем параметры */
}

/* анимация */
@keyframes downUp { 
  from {margin-top: 10px;}  
  50% {margin-top: 50px;}
  to {margin-top: 10px;}
}
```

```html
 <i class="down"></i>
```

Честно говоря, ресурсов про `css` анимацию и их параметры очень много. Стоит почитать. Для простых анимаций это несложно

Comment: Префикс `-moz` не нужен. `-webkit` зависит от поддерживаемых версий сафари, хрому уже не надо.

Comment: @Qwertiy так сойдет?)

Comment: Да.. Только, а alternate насколько кроссбраузерный? Помню, у меня с ним проблемы были.

Comment: @Qwertiy честно говоря, я не в курсе о нюансе этом. Я добавил анимацию без `alternate` еще. Можете свой ответ нарисовать, если думаете, что что-то у меня не то)